# Polimorfismo com interface e classe abstrata

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, typescript, polimorfismo

Como eu eu faço para que um método definido na interface `iDAO` seja repassado para ser implementado pela classe `ProprietarioDAO`, filha da classe abstrata `absDAO`, que implementa `iDAO`?

```
import { EntidadeDominio } from "../../models/EntidadeDominio/EntidadeDominio.model";

export interface iDao{    
    salvar( entidade: EntidadeDominio ): String;
    alterar( entidade: EntidadeDominio ): String;
    excluir( entidade: EntidadeDominio ): String;
    consultar( entidade: EntidadeDominio ): EntidadeDominio[];
}
```

```
import { iDao } from "./iDao.pattern";

export abstract class absDao implements iDao {    
    salvar;
    alterar;
    consultar;
    excluir;       
}
```

```
import { absDao } from "./absDao.pattern";

export class ProprietarioDAO extends absDao {    
    salvar(){    
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas a classe abstrata é só isso? Se for ela não faz o menor sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa pensar bem na forma que está trabalhando, ela me parece errada. Eu não tenho como dar muita dica de melhoria sem saber mais sobre o contexto, mas já seria um bom começo repensar o uso desta classe abstrata.

Digo, se você precisa que uma classe implemente a interface e também estenda a classe abstrata o certo seria fazer com que a classe final faça isto e remover estes métodos vazios da classe abstrata. E se a classe abstrata tiver apenas estes métodos, você pode simplesmente removê-la e fazer uso apenas da interface.

Por exemplo

```
export class ProprietarioDAO extends absDao implements iDao { }
```

e na class abstrata

```
export abstract class absDao {    
    // Propriedades em comum ou quaisquer outras coisas
}
```

De qualquer forma, você pode simplesmente fazer com que os métodos da classe abstrata sejam abstratos também, isso vai obrigar a classe filha a implementá-los.

```
export abstract class absDao implements iDao {    
    abstract salvar(entidade: EntidadeDominio): String;
    abstract alterar(entidade: EntidadeDominio): String;
    abstract consultar(entidade: EntidadeDominio): EntidadeDominio[];
    abstract excluir(entidade: EntidadeDominio): String;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Linq, agora entendi melhor. O intuíto era importar a interface apenas uma vez... Estou fazendo um projeto para a faculdade em Angular com TS para conhecer melhor o framework  e tentado aplicar alguns Design Patterns pra ver se funciona rsrs. Mais uma vez, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @HenriqueBatista De nada, por coincidência eu também estou trabalhando em um projeto em AngularJS com TypeScript xD